# how to use geocoder in android 2.2 emulator or android 2.1 device

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to use geocoder to get lang and lat from address for google map.am working in android sdk 2.2 .wen using geocoder is not working it throw exception. How to use geocoder  in my application.or any other methods available to get long and lat?

I have android 2.1 device .is there any possible to gecoder work in android 2.1 actual deevice.I saw one thread in web page in that they mentioned geocoder work fine in actual device 2.2.But i dont know it ll work on device 2.1 or not i checked but in device also geocoder not working.any one help me to solve my issues.

Thanks,

Lakshmanan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of the availability of Geocoder has nothing to do with the platform version (2.1 or 2.2), and everything to do with whether a library implementing the service (such as Google Maps) is available. (More information [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/RELEASENOTES.html) - search for "Maps external library")

[Here is the page explaining how to install it in your development environment](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing.html)

Take care though - you would do well to provide some kind of fallback in case the Google Maps library is not installed (for example, by querying the Google Maps Web API over HTTP when you detect that Geocoder is not implemented)

Comment: not true -- we run a Froyo emulator using the Google APIs system image (i.e. including the proprietary Maps code), and the GeoCoder is still not available. It looks like a bug in Froyo, since it used to work on older versions (specifically 1.6)

Comment: in fact, it *is* a bug in Froyo and Gingerbread, see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816