# Geocoder is not working in android

Tags: android, google-api

I am working on a program that takes address as an input from user and navigates the google map to that particular location,i have used getFromLocationName() method of geocoder but not getting the output, I am little afraid because i am not able to understand  the meaning of the below phrase given in the android site

> "The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included
>   in the core android framework. The Geocoder query methods will return
>   an empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the
>   isPresent() method to determine"

if that back end service is not present then how to get it..

but even when i try to use `isPresent()` method it is giving me compilation error,

plz suggest me, response will be very much appreciated

Comment: Are you using the emulator? I believe there are still issues with geocoding on the emulator. Also what is the error/ stack trace you get?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8816

Comment: yes i am not getting on my emulator...no error, it is running smoothly but it is not navigating to that particular given address,it is displaying the default map showing U.S.

Comment: it is not working in 2.2 version but working fine in 1.6..can anyone tell me how can i make it to work on 2.2

Comment: have a look at this :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022397/how-to-use-geocoder-in-android-2-2-emulator-or-android-2-1-device

Comment: i had google APIs by google inc,AndroidAPI8,revision2 installed already..but still my code is not running on 2.2 version.