# Geo coder backend service implementation in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working with geocode to convert latitude and longitude value in address.
This is not get return true  to is present(). How to make workable with geo coder?
Do I need to implement backed service for geocoder? If yes, how?

```
public String convert_address(){    
String address=" :: predefine address ::";

    try{
      Geocoder geocoder1;

    latitude = location.getLatitude();

    longitude = location.getLongitude();

    List<Address> addresses;

    geocoder1 = new Geocoder(mContext, Locale.getDefault());
    address=" geo enter";


     addresses = geocoder1.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 2);
     if(geocoder1.isPresent()==true)
         //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "it is present....", 500).show();
     address="...... present......";
         else
         //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"it is not....",500).show();
    address="....not present....";
     if(addresses != null) {
         Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
         StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("Address:\n");
         for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
         strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
         }
         address=strReturnedAddress.toString();
         }
         else{
         address="No Address returned!";
         }



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return address;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> public static boolean isPresent ()
>
> Returns true if the Geocoder methods getFromLocation and
> getFromLocationName are implemented. **Lack of network connectivity may
> still cause these methods to return null or empty lists.**

Comment: but in emulator also it return null if we pass dummy latitude AND LONGITUDE

Comment: wht is a option to get over from thissssss

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022397/how-to-use-geocoder-in-android-2-2-emulator-or-android-2-1-device